# route to another component if the form is actually submitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to redirect to another page when the form is actually submitted, but don't know how to go about this.

```
<div className="form-page">
                <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                    <h3>Admin Signup</h3>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        placeholder="Enter your name"
                    />

                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        placeholder="Email address"
                    />

                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="phone"
                        value={this.state.phone}
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                        placeholder="Phone number"
                    />

                    <input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        placeholder="password"
                    />
                    
                    <Link to="/dashboard"><button>Submit</button></Link>
                    
                    <p className="message">Already have an Account? <Link to="/signin" ><span>Sign in</span></Link></p>
                </form>
            </div>
```

I have been trying to do achieve this for long but couldn't, any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `<Link>` element wrapping the button.
And implement the `handleSubmit` method to do form validation and submit the input values.
After the submission is completed (maybe you can get the API call result inside the `handleSubmit` function), redirect to the target page using `this.props.history.push()`.